# Will I need to re-sand wood that has raised grain due to moisture?

Tags: wood, wood-finish

I am refinishing a cabinet with a barn wood plank top. After sanding it down to 220 grit I applied a coat of linseed oil. Unfortunately while at work today it rained, and while it wasn't directly exposed it got wet enough to raise the grains.

Will I need to re-sand after it dries?

Comment: Assume you're talking about "Boiled Linseed Oil" (BLO)?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion, I'm new to working with the stuff but I see that acronym a lot around here.

Comment: Seems like the answer is simply "if you don't want raised grain on your wood".

Comment: Bring it indoors, give it a week to dry fully, and see where you're at.   You shouldn't be keeping it outdoors if the final destination is indoors, it's going to change when it climatizes.

Comment: Yeah but sanding indoors is fairly messy.

Comment: @Wolf Harper this should be an answer. (or bring it in after sanding).+

Comment: FYI - this would have been a better fit for [woodworking.se]...

Answer (score 1):

Sanding oily wood will quickly ruin your sand paper. However, whether it should be resanded depends on how much you care about the finish. 
As a matter of practice, when I make "fine" wooden pieces, I purposely wet the wood after my first 220 sanding; after allowing it to dry, I sand off the fibers (or grain as you mentioned). And I sometimes repeat the wet, dry, and sand routine if I really need get rid of those fibers. I do this so that few fibers appear if the wood accidentally gets wet, or especially if I am planning to use a water based polyurethane to seal it.

Answer (score 1):

yes.  wet wood will not de-fuzz when it dries.